# Can't access the ubuntu server terminal after I accidentally stop the networking service

Tags: ubuntu, networking

After I typed and entered this command:

```
sudo /etc/init.d/networking stop
```

I can't access the ubuntu server in `putty`.

My question is: How do I start networking service again on the ubuntu server, if I can't access the server using `putty`.

I'm in Windows using `putty` to access the Ubuntu server.

Comment: Tell us more about the server. Is it at a hosting service? Does it have lights-out management?  Is its console attached to a KVM-over-IP switch? Does the kernel have vnc enabled? Is it powered by a network-controllable power source?

Comment: the ip 54.89.211.14 will direct to an apache2 default server/page.

Comment: I have searched for commands on how to enable networking. but in order to do so, i need to access the terminal and type the commands. but in my case I can't seem to access the terminal again.

Comment: I'm using windows, and using putty application to access the ubuntu server

Answer (score 2):

You're not going to be able to restart the server in-band (anything that requires networking on the server itself - SSH, Webmin, etc.).

Many hosting providers will offer Lights-Out Management in order to allow you to run remote maintenance or diagnostic commands. This includes features such as remote consoles or remote power commands. If you can not use a remote console, you can simply reboot the server, which will restart the networking service automatically.

As an example, the procedure for remotely restarting Digital Ocean servers is effectively the following:

1. Log in to your Digital Ocean account
2. Select the server you need to restart
3. Go the **Power** tab
4. Select **Power Cycle**

If you are not using Digital Ocean, many providers will have a similar workflow or procedure. You may need to poke around your hosting provider's control panel for the power switch.

If you do not have a hosting provider or they do not offer such technology, you will need to request your server be manually rebooted by support staff. However, most reputable providers will have a system for this.